# Post processing output of Palm detector model from MediaPipe

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, inference

I'm trying to use the tflite hand models from:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yiPfkhb4hSbXJZaSq9vDmhz24XVZmxpL/preview

I'm having trouble post processing the outputs of the palm detection model to get the bounding box for the palm in an input image.

""
Palm detector: 1) Predicted offset of predefined
anchors represented as a 1 x 896 x 18 tensor. 2)
Predicted detection confidence score of each anchor
represented as a 1 x 896 tensor.
""

The 2.) confidence score makes sense. However, I'm not sure what the 18 values in 1.) are. How do I know what the predefined anchors are (relative to the input image 128x128)? What are the 18 values in the third dim? It would make sense if it's a multiple of 4 since an offset bounding box needs 4 values, but it's not a multiple of 4. Maybe I don't properly understand the output of SSD models.

**In short, how do I postprocess the output of this model to get a final bounding box relative to the input dimensions 128x128?**

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue right now, and looks like there is no clear doc for that yet

Answer (score 0):

Do check out the link:

https://github.com/aashish2000/hand_tracking/blob/master/src/hand_tracker.py#L130

The 18 values are the offset (4 values) + 7 keypoints (knuckles, wrist base point, etc) that is also provided by the model.

This link below shows how those 7 keypoints look (scroll to later pages):
https://opencv.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Universal-Hand-Control.pdf

Might also want to check out the below link later:

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/456

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).